# Converting vector<char> that contains cbor data to const char *

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, char, message-queue

I have a uint8_t vector which contains cbor bytes and I have to cast or copy the bytes to a const char * to use in a POSIX message queue. I've tried the following approaches

```
vector<uint8_t> cbor_data{/*has some data*/};
const char *data = (const char *)(cbor_data.data());
```

and

```
vector<uint8_t> cbor_data{/*has some data*/};
char* data = new char[cbor_data.size() + 1];
memcpy(data, cbor_data.data(), cbor_data.size());
data[cbor_data.size()] = '\0';
```

But only a part of the data gets cast or copied. Both methods seem to fail. I have a few bytes whose value is 0. For example this is what I have in the vector:

```
a1,69,72,65,6d,69,6e,64,65,72,73,88,a5,66,63,6f,6e,66,69,67,a5,67,65,6e,61,62,6c,65,64,f4,72,72,65,6d,69,
6e,64,65,72,45,78,70,69,72,79,54,79,70,65,72,73,79,73,74,65,6d,43,61,6c,65,6e,64,61,72,54,69,6d,65,6c,72,
65,6d,69,6e,64,65,72,54,69,6d,65,00,66,76,69,65,77,65,64,f4,6b,77,72,69,74,65,41,63,63,65,73,73,66,72,65,
6d,6f,74,65,62,69,64,00,69,70,75,62,6c,69,73,68,65,72,a2,6c,64,6f,4e,6f,74,50,65,72,73,69,73,74,f5,6d,70
```

and this is what I am left with when I print data:

```
a1,69,72,65,6d,69,6e,64,65,72,73,88,a5,66,63,6f,6e,66,69,67,a5,67,65,6e,61,62,6c,65,64,f4,72,72,65,6d,69,
6e,64,65,72,45,78,70,69,72,79,54,79,70,65,72,73,79,73,74,65,6d,43,61,6c,65,6e,64,61,72,54,69,6d,65,6c,72,
65,6d,69,6e,64,65,72,54,69,6d,65,00
```

Everything after the 00 seems to be lost. Its not just while printing data. strlen(data) and cbor_data.size() dont match. Is there another way to go about this? Or a better way to pass a vector of char/uint8_t to a posix message queue?

Comment: As the char 00 is the string terminator, printing a char* will stop there. After that char, the rest probably is there. ;) Maybe you may substitute the 0 byte or have several `char*` strings.

Comment: Yes, are you printing the 00 directly as a char or do you first add the values of the characters '0' to each number before printing them out so that your print statement doesn't interpret 00 as the null terminator/end printing there? The printing seems to work fine with other numbers so it's difficult to say where the problem is. Have you tried a debugger or could you be more specific about how you print the data? If you are using the std::cout stream the problem is not in the printing, but if you aren't it might be.

Comment: If your string contains embedded nul characters, you need to pass a size along with it as its true size cannot be automatically determined. (This is one of the advantages of `std::string` over raw character arrays -- the other advantage being automatic memory management.) Note, for example, that `strlen("a\0b") == 1` even though the string is apparently 3 characters long.

Comment: @JoopEggen You're right! I was relying on strlen() and cbor_data.size() to match up. But strlen() also returns at the null terminator. But my problem still persists on the receiving end. I receive a cont char * (possibly containing null characters)  and the max message size which is way larger than the actual data sent.

Comment: What's your actual input? `vector<uint8_t>` or `cont char *`? If input is `cont char *` with given length, you may still put them in the buffer. However your question smells  like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @cdhowie According to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_send.3.html I have to pass a const char *. While sending the data I can pass the actual size but on the receiving end the buffer has size that is way greater than the actual message length.

Comment: Seems like you need to determine actual data length on receive end. Defining a header for data might be the way. Eg: first 4 bytes indicates length, then appended data are true data.

Comment: @SharatChandra So you should pass `cbor_data.size()` to `mq_send()` since that is the real length of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question:

> a better way to pass a vector of char/uint8_t to a posix message queue?

The actual question is in your comment,

> I can pass the actual size but on the receiving end the buffer has size that is way greater than the actual message length.

Since it's a raw pointer, and [mq_receive](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_receive.3.html) has to be given a larger size than msg's actual size.

The way to know actual data length on recv size is to define your own protocol of message.

Eg: First 4 bytes for data length, second 4 bytes stating source process tag, and rest of data is cbor data.

A simple chart:

```
================================================================
| Data Legnth | Process ID or insert what you want | cbor data |
================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, a char 00 terminates C style strings.

If the receiver expects [CBOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBOR), *binary data*, it should handle a 00 char.

00 = 3 bits 000 signifying an unsigned int + 5 bits payload 0-23 or a byte length indicator, in this case unsigned int payload 0. The unsigned int 0 could also be represent longer, but it always ends with at least one 0 byte.

You might try a "negative" integer with 0: 3 bits 001 + payload 00000.

So attempt substituting 00 with 0x40. No experience with CBOR, so not sure.